# Such difference between Edge Split as modelling tool and modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers

Why Edge Split doesn't dynamically apply its functions through animation?

Using it as a tool (Mesh->Edges->Edge Split) allows you to manipulate each face independently. However Edge Split modifier doesn't work like that. Yes it still increase vertex count but doesn't actually split geometry, unless click *Apply* button.

**Setup:**

**1.** Hook is binded to the top face with Sharp edge surrounding

**2.** Split Edge modifier is splitting top face

[image]

**Now animated hook is trying to move it:** There is no visible split.
[image]

**After pressing** *Apply* **in Edge Split modifer:** Whole different picture
[image]

[image]

Comment: As the name of the modifier suggesting it is splitting edges. So it's completely normal that after applying it, edges aren't connected. You can try AutoSmooth instead.

Comment: The modifier only takes effect after your mesh is moved. That's with every modifier.

Comment: LukeD, so why it splits edges and at the same time keeps them connected before applying?

Mr Zak, in edit mode select vertices and hit CTRL H

Comment: Because the nature of modifiers is that they are non-destructive tools. Same thing is for example with Subdivision Surface and Bevel. Both are creating additional faces/vertices but you can edit them only after applying modifiers. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html

Comment: When you edit a mesh, you edit its state _before_ modification. So while the modifier is live, it will split the edges wherever you have put them. After application,  you move the edges after they have been split.

Answer (score 1):

> so why it splits edges and at the same time keeps them connected
>   before applying?

Edge split modifier actually split geometry. But you test this using wrong way. Try to add Susurf after Edge Split:

[image]

When you adding hooks it moves both arrays of vertex, that splitted by edge split modifier

Comment: If it clones edges that are already binded to Hook, then why after applying these copied edges aren't belong to Hook?

Comment: Looks like new vertex lose some information about hooks, while applying. It looks like a bug, but not a rule

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I understood your problem but i suggest you to split the only desired face by this method:

1:Select
[image: Step 1 Select]

2:Press Ctrl+E

[image]

3: Click on Edge Split

[image]

And the results would be much better. By this only your desired face will be splitted as it also does not cause increase in unwanted geometery...

Comment: Main thing, why I am bothering with this modifier - is ability to merge this face back later in animation. If I split it in edit mode, I couldn't use Subsurf modifier for example or Bevel. Yes I can use Explode+Particle System, but I was hoping to find different approach.